# Mongo Collection Name too long: ns name too long, max size is 128 mongo

Tags: perl, mongodb

While create a mongo collection, the name is 123 char long. Mongo throws this error(ns name too long, max size is 128 mongo) when I try to create the collection. It has nothing to do with indexing. If I change the name to a smaller name, then it works fine. 
How can I make mongo to accepts long string for the collection name?

Thanks

Comment: what's the name of the database?

Answer (score 1):

ns means namespace - that would be the name of your database, "." and the name of your collection.  If your collection name is 123 characters, you only have four characters left for the database name.

Comment: is there anyway to increase this limit?

Comment: @user2387745 Don't believe so, why would you want such a long name?

Comment: It's part of our flow and the names need to be that big. I cant change that requirement.

Comment: Note database are limited to 64 characters. So a good practice would be to limit collection names to 63 characters.Source for the limit: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/